# Getting graphs from the Google Chart API with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, access-control, google-visualization

I'm trying to get a chart from the Google Chart API using jQuery $.post but I'm hitting the Access Control Allow Origin restriction of the XMLHttpRequest.

What's the *right* way to do get a Google chart in jQuery?

Note : I have a dataset that's larger than 2k so need to use POST rather than just attach it to the end of the URL in an img tag.

Comment: Probably you have to create a server side script on your domain that acts as a proxy and forwards the post request to google.
This way you can make the jQuery call directly to your server side script.

Comment: Thanks Luciano Mammino, I'm thinking that may be my best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I followed Luciano Mammino's advice and called the Google Chart API from my server.

On the whole, I think this is a good solution.